# How to fix Transient ANRs without any information from my package?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

**ANR keyDispatchingTimedOut
in com.pinkpointer.wordsearch2/com.pinkpointer.wordsbase.ActivityMain**

I receive a lot of ANR reports from Google Play users, but there isn't any trace of my package (com.pinkpointer.wordsearch2) on the logs.

How do I fix/avoid this kind of ANRs? What should I do to investigate what is causing this?

ANR:

```
----- pid 254 at 2016-01-01 19:58:47 -----
Cmd line: system_server
DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0 hwl=0 hwll=0)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x400a1390 self=0x107d0
  | sysTid=254 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=-1344838376
  | schedstat=( 7892195029 5071214745 23360 )
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:834)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:538)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:732)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
"android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread" prio=5 tid=57 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a0dfc0 self=0x6796c8
  | sysTid=2268 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=5212544
  | schedstat=( 11065007 6464458 49 )
  at android.hardware.SensorManager.sensors_data_poll(Native Method)
  at android.hardware.SensorManager$SensorThread$SensorThreadRunnable.run(SensorManager.java:477)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1050)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=56 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40a16770 self=0x4747e8
  | sysTid=609 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=5316008
  | schedstat=( 6316366825 4713624985 22272 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=55 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407d8190 self=0x3bc340
  | sysTid=424 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4503928
  | schedstat=( 6187271007 4849806583 22349 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=54 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409c9090 self=0x3c7e68
  | sysTid=423 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4236968
  | schedstat=( 6024395834 4922174710 22352 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=53 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408bf990 self=0x420ff0
  | sysTid=407 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3541200
  | schedstat=( 8267383 48501001 19 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x408bfb18> (a java.lang.VMThread)
  at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1455)
  at java.lang.LangAccessImpl.parkFor(LangAccessImpl.java:79)
  at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:368)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:188)
  at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2047)
  at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1052)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:612)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1050)
"RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@408bbbb0" daemon prio=5 tid=52 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40929ba0 self=0x48efa8
  | sysTid=404 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4769000
  | schedstat=( 321462 16333461 5 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40751f40> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:426)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:138)
  at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:111)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.RefQueueWorker.run(RefQueueWorker.java:133)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1050)
"ServerHangDetectThread" prio=5 tid=51 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407f19b0 self=0x484588
  | sysTid=402 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4736704
  | schedstat=( 39651157 6059385 249 )
  at java.lang.VMThread.sleep(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1244)
  at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1226)
  at com.android.server.ServerHangDetectThread.run(SystemServer.java:896)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=50 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4083ac18 self=0x4834d8
  | sysTid=401 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4732056
  | schedstat=( 6030052379 4673184964 22240 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=49 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4083ab50 self=0x4827e8
  | sysTid=400 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4682768
  | schedstat=( 7293367117 4695840005 22494 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=48 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409159c0 self=0x4815f0
  | sysTid=399 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4721496
  | schedstat=( 7281515245 4914823537 22579 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=47 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409158f8 self=0x480858
  | sysTid=398 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4719880
  | schedstat=( 7033367700 5022757215 22670 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"GPSTimeUpdate" prio=5 tid=46 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40809998 self=0x476548
  | sysTid=376 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4677544
  | schedstat=( 8951848 8224691 5 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"NWTimeUpdate" prio=5 tid=45 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40811390 self=0x450ee0
  | sysTid=375 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4677800
  | schedstat=( 10011460 14925462 19 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"ThrottleService" prio=5 tid=44 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40863900 self=0x4502c0
  | sysTid=373 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3569064
  | schedstat=( 9072384 12999154 12 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"LocationManagerService" prio=5 tid=41 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408b7d18 self=0x44cdd0
  | sysTid=368 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=4526488
  | schedstat=( 161454234 2433614618 551 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at com.android.server.LocationManagerService.run(LocationManagerService.java:652)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1050)
"watchdog" prio=5 tid=43 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405a2138 self=0x408308
  | sysTid=361 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=118240
  | schedstat=( 14968764 10462155 46 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405a2138> (a com.android.server.Watchdog)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:426)
  at com.android.server.Watchdog.run(Watchdog.java:435)
"AMPlus" prio=5 tid=42 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408f9820 self=0x36c5e8
  | sysTid=356 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3739480
  | schedstat=( 7176075 3178078 6 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"backup" prio=5 tid=40 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407fcd70 self=0x394050
  | sysTid=342 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=4126848
  | schedstat=( 33539461 1132776537 178 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"AudioProfileService" prio=5 tid=39 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408b8718 self=0x371f78
  | sysTid=327 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3750280
  | schedstat=( 10871308 13329539 8 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at com.mediatek.audioprofile.AudioProfileService$OverrideSystemThread.run(AudioProfileService.java:3359)
"SoundPoolThread" prio=5 tid=38 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40950a78 self=0x371d60
  | sysTid=320 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4311776
  | schedstat=( 3175000 597616 20 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"SoundPool" prio=5 tid=37 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409510b0 self=0x371988
  | sysTid=319 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1597416
  | schedstat=( 201539 172770 1 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"AudioService" prio=5 tid=36 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4096f340 self=0x41c720
  | sysTid=318 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4311128
  | schedstat=( 14293848 14088612 26 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.media.AudioService$AudioSystemThread.run(AudioService.java:1685)
"VoldConnector" prio=5 tid=35 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407da378 self=0x41b880
  | sysTid=316 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4303880
  | schedstat=( 13529233 11921845 37 )
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:60)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:123)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:198)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:169)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1050)
"NativeDaemonConnector" prio=5 tid=34 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407b57e8 self=0x419dd8
  | sysTid=315 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4300560
  | schedstat=( 15321229 26878538 24 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"MountService" prio=5 tid=33 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4088db88 self=0x418df0
  | sysTid=314 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4296488
  | schedstat=( 6999001 6626923 3 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"WifiP2PService" prio=5 tid=32 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409afc00 self=0x416d48
  | sysTid=313 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4291408
  | schedstat=( 7028615 47077 3 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"Tethering" prio=5 tid=31 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40811c50 self=0x415cd8
  | sysTid=312 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4283920
  | schedstat=( 7344846 2107538 8 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"WifiService" prio=5 tid=30 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408a0d70 self=0x414758
  | sysTid=311 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4278416
  | schedstat=( 19542306 18320384 43 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"ConnectivityThread" prio=5 tid=29 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4080bd28 self=0x412748
  | sysTid=310 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4270208
  | schedstat=( 776195614 961300779 2584 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at com.android.server.ConnectivityService$ConnectivityThread.run(ConnectivityService.java:334)
"NetdConnector" prio=5 tid=28 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408f1db8 self=0x411a20
  | sysTid=308 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4266840
  | schedstat=( 6111620 10322073 57 )
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(Native Method)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.access$400(LocalSocketImpl.java:60)
  at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:123)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.listenToSocket(NativeDaemonConnector.java:198)
  at com.android.server.NativeDaemonConnector.run(NativeDaemonConnector.java:169)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1050)
"NativeDaemonConnector" prio=5 tid=27 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407a6110 self=0x18d40
  | sysTid=307 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=102968
  | schedstat=( 7371538 6642077 4 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"BluetoothProfileState:0" prio=5 tid=26 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4086d0e0 self=0x1c3a0
  | sysTid=306 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=115928
  | schedstat=( 6911001 5148461 3 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"BluetoothProfileState:1" prio=5 tid=25 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4069ccb0 self=0x19ac0
  | sysTid=305 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=107576
  | schedstat=( 7211152 1201232 6 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"InputReader" prio=10 tid=24 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408a0420 self=0x178d8
  | sysTid=304 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=94176
  | schedstat=( 3858795362 1717710002 19803 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"InputDispatcher" prio=10 tid=23 SUSPENDED
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408a0238 self=0x16e80
  | sysTid=303 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=120128
  | schedstat=( 5954534638 2779652147 43997 )
  at android.os.Process.sendSignal(Native Method)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.dumpStackTraces(ActivityManagerService.java:3276)
  at com.android.server.am.ANRManager$AnrDumpMgr.dumpAnrDebugInfoLocked(SourceFile:815)
  at com.android.server.am.ANRManager$AnrDumpMgr.dumpAnrDebugInfo(SourceFile:687)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.appNotResponding(ActivityManagerService.java:3569)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.keyDispatchingTimedOut(ActivityRecord.java:694)
  at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$InputMonitor.notifyANR(WindowManagerService.java:5630)
  at com.android.server.InputManager$Callbacks.notifyANR(InputManager.java:409)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"WindowManagerPolicy" prio=5 tid=22 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4084cc00 self=0x401f20
  | sysTid=302 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4202584
  | schedstat=( 5517355204 4479214783 9902 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$PolicyThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:688)
"WindowManager" prio=5 tid=21 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4076fe40 self=0x3ff758
  | sysTid=301 nice=-4 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4192744
  | schedstat=( 5782637976 2148648109 9678 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at com.android.server.WindowManagerService$WMThread.run(WindowManagerService.java:646)
"AlarmManager" prio=5 tid=20 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407fc390 self=0x3fe8e8
  | sysTid=300 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4188704
  | schedstat=( 1721062074 2854937691 1714 )
  at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService.waitForAlarm(Native Method)
  at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService.access$1200(AlarmManagerService.java:98)
  at com.android.server.AlarmManagerService$AlarmThread.run(AlarmManagerService.java:855)
"PowerManagerService" prio=5 tid=19 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4095cbf0 self=0x3fb7c0
  | sysTid=299 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4131096
  | schedstat=( 367204117 636317446 1585 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"PowerManagerService.mScreenOffThread" prio=5 tid=17 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4089b8f0 self=0x3fb438
  | sysTid=298 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4175216
  | schedstat=( 32362383 39819461 42 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"UEventObserver" prio=5 tid=18 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40683fc8 self=0x3f4c90
  | sysTid=297 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=4117480
  | schedstat=( 1523551256 1877781525 1877 )
  at android.os.UEventObserver.next_event(Native Method)
  at android.os.UEventObserver.access$100(UEventObserver.java:70)
  at android.os.UEventObserver$UEventThread.run(UEventObserver.java:133)
"SyncHandlerThread" prio=5 tid=16 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x407b5978 self=0x356218
  | sysTid=295 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3504752
  | schedstat=( 144224083 1621992835 550 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"AccountManagerService" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x408fd408 self=0x365700
  | sysTid=293 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3534616
  | schedstat=( 6656923 6519077 2 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"FileObserver" prio=5 tid=14 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406ed0a0 self=0x365900
  | sysTid=292 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3571288
  | schedstat=( 162676768 255155919 724 )
  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
  at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:119)
"PackageManager" prio=5 tid=13 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x406094e8 self=0x1d4130
  | sysTid=291 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=bg_non_interactive handle=3547712
  | schedstat=( 2052548238 1680291011 1951 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"AnrMonitorThread" prio=5 tid=12 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405e4410 self=0x35d6d8
  | sysTid=290 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1914656
  | schedstat=( 5875232 15902924 17 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:91)
"ProcessStats" prio=5 tid=11 TIMED_WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405dcb78 self=0x35d9e8
  | sysTid=289 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3535688
  | schedstat=( 97410225 25609083 150 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x405dcb78> (a com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:426)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1797)
"ActivityManager" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x405a3788 self=0x353530
  | sysTid=287 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3487336
  | schedstat=( 9125782587 2019756449 8646 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$AThread.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1615)
"android.server.ServerThread" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4059afa8 self=0x344058
  | sysTid=286 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3407712
  | schedstat=( 12537831838 8015630044 25223 )
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:151)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:363)
  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:750)
"java.lang.ProcessManager" daemon prio=5 tid=8 WAIT
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40591e78 self=0x3442b8
  | sysTid=284 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=3483352
  | schedstat=( 875154 7964464 6 )
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
  - waiting on <0x40591ce0> (a java.util.HashMap)
  at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:389)
  at java.lang.ProcessManager.onExit(ProcessManager.java:170)
  at java.lang.ProcessManager.watchChildren(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ProcessManager$1.run(ProcessManager.java:116)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=7 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058d5b8 self=0x201040
  | sysTid=260 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2832656
  | schedstat=( 6291644569 4914445014 22608 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"BinderThd_AP254" prio=5 tid=6 NATIVE
  | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058d328 self=0x1d4d08
  | sysTid=259 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2116744
  | schedstat=( 5921786788 4702650890 22638 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=5 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058c408 self=0x1653a8
  | sysTid=258 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2116544
  | schedstat=( 2732817466 3439506840 10518 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058c348 self=0x1d29c0
  | sysTid=257 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=2116344
  | schedstat=( 38528460 22060924 11 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=3 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058c2a0 self=0x2b37d8
  | sysTid=256 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=558776
  | schedstat=( 8881855777 5367786458 5326 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
"HeapWorker" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
  | group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4058c1e8 self=0x1cfea8
  | sysTid=255 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=599272
  | schedstat=( 2210836931 590081921 1885 )
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
----- end 254 -----
```

Full ANR log: http://pastebin.com/9cqnBNGa

Comment: Please post your `activitymain`